# Relationship of offset in glMapBufferRange(...) and first in glDrawArraysInstanced(...)

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm struggling to understand the relationship between the offset variables in the two functions and how the offset value affects `gl_VertexID` and `gl_InstanceID` variables in the shader.

Through reading of the functions documentation, I think `glMapBufferRange` expects `offset` to be the number of bytes from the start of the buffer, whereas `glDrawArraysInstanced` expects `first` to be the the number of strides as specified by `glVertexAttribPointer`.

However that doesn't seem to be the case, as the below code doesn't work if `offsetVerts` has a value different from 0. For 0 it renders 3 squares on the screen, as I expected it.

The other possible error source would be the value of gl_VertexID. I'd expect it to be 0,1,2,3 for the 4 vertex shader calls per instance, regardless of the offset value.
Just to make sure I also tried using a first value that is multiple of 4 and `vertices[int(mod(gl_VertexID,4))]` for the position lookup, without success.

How can I alternate the code to make it work with offsets other than 0?

glGetError() calls are omitted here to shorten the code, it's 0 through the whole process. GL version is 3.3.

Init code:

```
GLuint buff_id, v_id;
GLint bytesPerVertex = 2*sizeof(GLfloat); //8

glGenBuffers( 1, &buff_id );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buff_id );
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &v_id );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1024, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW );

glBindVertexArray( v_id );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( posLoc );
glVertexAttribPointer( posLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, bytesPerVertex, (void *)0 );
glVertexAttribDivisor( posLoc, 1 );
glBindVertexArray( 0 );

glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
float *data_ptr = nullptr;

int numVerts = 3;
int offsetVerts = 0;
```

render code:

```
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buff_id );
data_ptr = (float *)glMapBufferRange( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
    bytesPerVertex * offsetVerts, 
    bytesPerVertex * numVerts,
    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT );

data_ptr[0] = 50;
data_ptr[1] = 50;
data_ptr[2] = 150;
data_ptr[3] = 50;
data_ptr[4] = 250;
data_ptr[5] = 50;

glUnmapBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );

glBindVertexArray( v_id );
glDrawArraysInstanced( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, offsetVerts, 4, 3 );
glBindVertexArray( 0 );
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330
uniform mat4 proj;
in vec2 pos;

void main() {

  vec2 vertices[4]= vec2[4](
    vec2(pos.x,         pos.y),
    vec2(pos.x + 10.0f, pos.y),
    vec2(pos.x,         pos.y + 10.0f ),
    vec2(pos.x + 10.0f, pos.y + 10.0f )
    );

  gl_Position = proj * vec4(vertices[gl_VertexID], 1, 1);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330
out vec4 LFragment;
void main() {
  LFragment = vec4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The other possible error source would be the value of `gl_VertexID`. I'd expect it to be 0,1,2,3 for the 4 vertex shader calls per instance, regardless of the `offset` value.

There is **no** `offset` value in `glDrawArrays*`

The base function for this is 
`glDrawArrays(type, first, count)`, and this just will generate primitives from a consecutive sub-array of the specified vertex attribute arrays, from index `frist` to `frist+count-1`. Hence, `gl_VertexID` will be in the range `first`,`first+count-1`.

You are actually not using any vertex attribute array, you turned your attribute into an *per-instance* attribute. But the `first` parameter will **not** introduce an offset into these. You can either adjust your attribute pointer to include the offset, or you can use [`glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance) to specify the offset you need.

Note that the `gl_InstanceID` will not reflect the base instance you set there, it will still count from 0 relative to the begin of the draw call. But the actuall instance values fetched from the array will use the offset.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. If I e.g. use `first=1` and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, does that mean that, vertices 1,2,3 will form the first triangle, or will it be some undefined behavior because vertex 0 of the 0,1,2 triangle is not specified?

Comment: It just means it will from the first triangle from the vertices 1,2,3. There is nothing undefined about it. In your use case, setting `first` to anything but zero just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The code specifically maps an offset buffer to the local adress space. So say `offsetVerts` is 2, then vertices 0 and 1 will not be written, but 2,3,4. When then using `first=0`, wouldn't it result in an undefined read?

Comment: @G.Grantig. No. you don not have any vertex attribute array enabled (at least in the pasted code). As a result, there is no fetch. All you have are _per-instance_ attributes, and your current draw call always fetches from offset 0 relative to the pointer you have set. And _that_ will result in reading undefined values when `offsetVerts` is not 0, but you use `glDrawArraysInstanced` which _alwyas_ starts fetching data for the 0-th instance.

Comment: I see, so first does not affect per-instance attributes. I thought it would. To make sure If I added a float attribute f and used `first=2`, with the buffer [xxxyyyzzzaaabbb...] I'd get the result:
(pos=xx, f=z), (pos=xx, f=a), (pos=xx, f=b) ...?

Comment: @G.Grantig: I can' answer your question. The buffer contents are only one thing, the attribute pointers are another. For each enabled attribute array (real vertex attribm so attrib divisior == 0), the GL will fetch the `i`-th attribute at byte offset `pointer + i * stride` (with pointer basically containing the name of the buffer + the byte offset within it). With `glDrawArrays(...,first,count)`, `i` will just be in the range `[first, first+count-1]`.

Comment: @G.Grantig: And actually, having the `first` parameter of `glDrawArraysInstanced` influence the instance IDs would not make the slightest sense for the use case it is designed for: drawing `primcount` instances of the same base geometry. `first` just affects that base geometry, and the instance data is completely orthogonal to that. Setting an offset for both with just one parameter would be just absurd.